# How to show my replies in threads when checking gmail with mutt via imap?

Tags: gmail, imap, mutt

With my local maildir, I acomplish this by storing replies in the same folder as mail received. But Gmail stores sent and received messages in separate folders (labels). I've tried setting spoolfile to [Gmail]/All but then I see messages that should be removed.

Can mutt show messages from two folders at once?

Can gmail be configured to automatically add specified label to sent and received messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you send outgoing messages with Gmail's smtp server, then the filtering machinery applies even for outgoing messages, and they should show in the labels you have assigned.  Unfortunately, I do not know if this is possible if you use sendmail, postfix or some other local MTA to send outgoing email.